# Timezone Issue Snowflake

Tags: sql, timezone

Have a table XYZ replicated from SAP . SAP timezone is UTC . When a record is created in SAP CREATED_DATE column is saved as TIMESTAMP and UTC timezone

Snowflake timezone is CST

If i have to select records from XYZ where CREATED_DATE = CURRENT_DATE in SNOWFLAKE what should i do

Comment: Hello.  Your question is unclear.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considering `UTC` is `Universal Time Coordinated` and `CST` is `Central Standard Time`, `UTC` is six hours ahead of `CST`. So, you need to add 6 hours to snowflake's `CURRENT_DATE` for its UTC equivalent, or substract 6 hours from `CREATED_DATE`.

Comment: Not always.  CST might mean China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or Central Standard Time.  Even in the latter case, it may be that the OP meant *Central Time* which might be on CST or CDT depending on the value being converted.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Kind of yes, OP should clarify that. But when not, are we going to think about every other possible meaning of any abbreviation? Like Unwanted Tackle Count? :) What cames to mind in the first place is universal time coordinated and central standard time; to my mind. Don't know about anybody elses.